# div with jquery horizontal scroll issue

Tags: css

[image: horizontal scroll issue]

I load main div with jquery ,

why I get horizontal scroll
I try to a void it but it still exist

how to remove this horizontal  scroll

https://jsfiddle.net/6Lou3bgf/

note: I want main div with width :300px
please not change mainpanel-wrapper display: flex;

```
<style>
    .mainpanel-wrapper {width: fit-content;display: flex;margin:0 auto;top:60px;position: absolute;height:calc(100% - 60px);}
    .sidebar_panel {display: flex; flex: 0 1 auto;  float:right;    width: fit-content;overflow-y: auto;}
    .panel2 { display:inline-block;   flex: 1;width: fit-content;}
</style>

<div style="height: 100%; position: absolute; user-select: block; top: 0px; left: 0px; right: 0px; background-color: rgb(40, 51, 64); display: flex; flex-direction: column; overflow: hidden;">

            <div  id="mainpanel-wrapper" class="mainpanel-wrapper">

                <div  id="sidebar_panel2" style="background-color:#0F0;" class="sidebar_panel panel2">
                
                <div id="main" style="overflow: hidden !important; width:300px; margin:0;padding:0px; display:inline-block;" >
    <div style="display:inline-block;width:auto; margin-top:10px;cursor: pointer; width: 100%; position: relative; background-color:#FFFFFF; direction: rtl;"  >
        <div style="width:100%; background-color:#F00; height: 110px;">
                xxx
        </div>
    </div> 
    <div style="display:inline-block;width:auto ; margin-top:10px;cursor: pointer; width: 100%; position: relative; background-color:#FFFFFF; direction: rtl;"  >
        <div style="width:100%; background-color:#F00; height: 110px;">
                xxx
        </div>
    </div> 
    <div style="display:inline-block;width:auto margin-top:10px;cursor: pointer; width: 100%; position: relative; background-color:#FFFFFF; direction: rtl;"  >
        <div style="width:100%; background-color:#F00; height: 110px;">
                xxx
        </div>
    </div> 
    <div style="display:inline-block;width:auto; margin-top:10px;cursor: pointer; width: 100%; position: relative; background-color:#FFFFFF; direction: rtl;"  >
        <div style="width:100%; background-color:#F00; height: 110px;">
                xxx
        </div>
    </div> 
    <div style="display:inline-block;width:auto; margin-top:10px;cursor: pointer; width: 100%; position: relative; background-color:#FFFFFF; direction: rtl;"  >
        <div style="width:100%; background-color:#F00; height: 110px;">
                xxx
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>      
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Add your jQuery code. Html code works fine and doesn't have horizontal scrolling.

Comment: @Amini ,I put all code , please review it , and not change mainpanel-wrapper display: flex;

Comment: Can you remove all styles, all classes and all superflous content?

Comment: @aloisdg ,the simple content for testing , why remove all style, classes , I use it;

Comment: because, to help you, we need a [MCVE] (enhance the minimal.)

Comment: @aloisdg ; that is very simple and minimal

Comment: @samieisa Does removing `pointer: cursor` help?

Comment: @aloisdg ; no do not make any affect

Comment: If it do not make any effect, that is not very simple nor minimal. Remove everything not needed.

Comment: @aloisdg , the issue in this code .panel2 {  display:flex;    flex :1; width:300px;} , how to fit this  without no longer width contents , how to do this flex with fit it's content

Comment: @samieisa add this kind of detail into your question. Remove unrelated stuff like `pointer: cursor`